# Inquiry about using if statement with Widget what these dots meaning if(condition) ...[ ]

Tags: if-statement, flutter, conditional-statements

Inquiry about using if statement with Widget.What these three dots meaning if(condition) ...[something ]

For example:

```dart
if (_imageFile != null) ...[
             Image.file(
               _imageFile,
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             ),
             Row(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Expanded(
                   child: FlatButton(
                     child: Icon(Icons.crop),
                     onPressed: _cropImage,
                   ),
                 ),
                 Expanded(
                     child: FlatButton(
                   child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                   onPressed: _clear,
                 ))
               ],
             ),
             Uploader(file: _imageFile) ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...` is the spread operator. It adds all the items of an iterable inside another list, such that:

```dart
[
  'a',
  ...['b', 'c,'],
  'd',
]
```

gives `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

The `if` placed before just makes it conditional, such that the items are not added to the list if the condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is at https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists

basically it will add all the content of the list after the '...' operator to the current list.

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
///list2 becomes [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

more at https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md